# Delete data from Json Array in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm try to delete data from my json array inside recyclerview. I can able to delete the same data from the server.But it is not reflected on my recyclerview. it is reflected when reloading the activity.

This is my **Adapter page**

```
public class RecyclerAdapterMyLink extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterMyLink.ViewHolder> {
    List<RecyclerMyLinkModel> mLinks;
private Context context;
private static final String DELETEMYLINK_URL = Config.GET_URL+"deletemylink.php";

public RecyclerAdapterMyLink(List<RecyclerMyLinkModel> mLinks, Context context){
    super();
    this.mLinks = mLinks;
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public RecyclerAdapterMyLink.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rsmylink_activicty, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(contactView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    RecyclerMyLinkModel myLinkModel = mLinks.get(position);
    holder.txtLinkTitle.setText(myLinkModel.getCaption());
    holder.txtLinkTitle.setTag(myLinkModel.getLink());
    holder.remove_mylinks.setTag(myLinkModel.getLid());
    holder.remove_mylinks.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    holder.remove_mylinks.setTag(holder);
}
View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

       ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        int position = holder.getPosition();
        AlertDialog diaBox = AskOption(position);
        diaBox.show();
    }
};
private AlertDialog AskOption(Integer pos)
{
    final Integer post=pos;
    AlertDialog myQuittingDialogBox =new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            //set message, title, and icon
            .setTitle("Delete")
            .setMessage("Do you want to Delete")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.heartred)
            .setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        RecyclerMyLinkModel feedItem = mLinks.get(post);
                        Integer lid=feedItem.getLid();
                        RemoveMyLInk(lid);//Deleted from server
                        mLinks.remove(post);
                        notifyItemRemoved(post);;
                        notifyItemRangeChanged(post, mLinks.size());
                        dialog.dismiss();
                }

            })
            .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            })
            .create();
    return myQuittingDialogBox;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mLinks.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView remove_mylinks;
    public TextView txtLinkTitle;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        remove_mylinks = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_mylinks);

        txtLinkTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtLinkTitle);

    }

}
private void RemoveMyLInk(Integer lkid)
{

    class RemoveMyLinkUser extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            Integer myNum = params[0];
            try {

                URL url = new URL(DELETEMYLINK_URL); // here is your URL path

                JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
                postDataParams.put("l_id", myNum);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new
                            InputStreamReader(
                            conn.getInputStream()));

                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                    String line="";

                    while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                        sb.append(line);
                        break;
                    }

                    in.close();
                    return sb.toString();

                }
                else {
                    return new String("false : "+responseCode);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            if ("Some Problem Occurs Try Again".equals(s))
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if("Successfully Deleted".equals(s))
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }


    }
    RemoveMyLinkUser ch = new RemoveMyLinkUser();
    ch.execute(lkid);
}
public String getPostDataString(JSONObject params) throws Exception {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

    while(itr.hasNext()){

        String key= itr.next();
        Object value = params.get(key);

        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));

    }
    return result.toString();
}
}
```

This is my Recyclerview layout

[image]

Comment: Not sure if it's causing problems or not but you shouldn't need this line notifyItemRangeChanged(post, mLinks.size()); notifyItemRemoved will take care of that for you.

Comment: @Ben i remove the code .But same result

Comment: [you don't know java's basics: Integer is not int, Integer is an Object ...](http://ideone.com/1dX3tD)

Comment: @Selvin Great man, its working this my first project. Thanks. how can i help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information Integer is not int, Integer is an Object. So please change the Integer to int. Like this

```
private AlertDialog AskOption(int pos)
{
final int post=pos;
AlertDialog myQuittingDialogBox =new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        //set message, title, and icon
        .setTitle("Delete")
        .setMessage("Do you want to Delete")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.heartred)
        .setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    RecyclerMyLinkModel feedItem = mLinks.get(post);
                    Integer lid=feedItem.getLid();
                    RemoveMyLInk(lid);//Deleted from server
                    mLinks.remove(post);
                    notifyItemRemoved(post);;
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(post, mLinks.size());
                    dialog.dismiss();
            }

        })
        .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        })
        .create();
return myQuittingDialogBox;
}
```

Credits @Selvin

This answer is just only for information to others